# EF Core deadlock with multi threads + BeginTransaction + Commit

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-deadlocks

I have some questions regarding how `SaveChangesAsync()` and `BeginTransaction()` + `transaction.Commit()` work.

My team has a .NET Core worker that receives events from Microsoft EventHub and saves data into SQL server via EF Core 3.
One of event types has a lot of data, so we created a few tables, separate data and then save it into these tables. The child tables reference the parent table's `id` column (FK_Key).
Some data in the DB has to be deleted before new data is saved under certain conditions, so we delete -> upsert data.

To save data into the DB, we call `dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` and `transaction.Commit()`. When we run the worker, we get deadlock exception like `Transaction (Process ID 71) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

I found that one of  `.BatchDeleteAsync()` in `PurgeDataInChildTables()` or one of `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync()` in `Upsert()` throws a deadlock exception (it changes every time I run the worker).

Here is the code:

```
public async Task DeleteAndUpsert(List<MyEntity> entitiesToDelete, List<MyEntity> entitiesToUpsert)
{
    if (entitiesToDelete.Any())
        await myRepository.Delete(entitiesToDelete);

    if (entitiesToUpsert.Any())
        await myRepository.Upsert(entitiesToUpsert);
}


public override async Task Upsert(IList<MyEntity> entities)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(DbContextOptions, DbOptions))
    {
        using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            await PurgeDataInChildTables(entities, dbContext);
            await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities);
            // tables that depends on the parent table (FK_Key)
            await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany<Child1>(x => x.Id).ToList());
            await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany<Child2>(x => x.Id).ToList());
            await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany<Child3>(x => x.Id).ToList());
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}

public override async Task Delete(IList<MyEntity> entities)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(DbContextOptions, DbOptions))
    {
        using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            await PurgeDataInChildTables(entities, dbContext);
            await dbContext.BulkDeleteAsync(entities);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}

private async Task PurgeDataInChildTables(IList<MyEntity> entities, MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    var ids = entities.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    await dbContext.Child1.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).BatchDeleteAsync();
    await dbContext.Child2.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).BatchDeleteAsync();
    await dbContext.Child3.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).BatchDeleteAsync();
}
```

When the worker starts up, it creates four threads and they all upsert to the same table (and delete too). So, I assume that deadlock occurs when one thread starts a transaction and another starts another transaction (or something similar..) and then try to upsert to (or delete from) child tables.
I tried some stuff to solve the issue and noticed that deadlock seems to be resolved when I remove `BeginTransaction()` and use `SaveChangesAsync()` instead.

Here is the modified code:

```
public override async Task Upsert(IList<MyEntity> entities)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(DbContextOptions, DbOptions))
    {
        await PurgeDataInChildTables(entities, dbContext);
        await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities);
        // tables that depends on the parent table (FK_Key)
        await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany(x => x.Child1).ToList());
        await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany(x => x.Child2).ToList());
        await dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities.SelectMany(x => x.Child3).ToList());
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public override async Task Delete(IList<MyEntity> entities)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(DbContextOptions, DbOptions))
    {
        await PurgeDataInChildTables(entities, dbContext);
        await dbContext.BulkDeleteAsync(entities);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Deadlock was occuring ~ 30 seconds after the worker starts up but it didn't occur for 2 ~ 3 mins when I modified the code, so I think the issue is resolved, thought it might still occur if I run the worker longer.

Finally, here are my questions:

- When I use `BeginTransaction()` + `.Commit()` deadlock occurs but it won't happen when I use `SaveChangesAsync()`. Why is it?
- What is the difference between the two methods in terms of transaction?
- If the modified code still could cause deadlock or not a good solution, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say precisely without looking into profiling session of the database. The thing that needs to be looked up there is what kind of locks are taken (where it is `shared` and where it is `exclusive` or `update`) and when transaction are **actually** opened. I will describe a theoretical behaviour that needs to be proved with actual database profiling.

**When you wrap everything with Database.BeginTransaction()**:
Isolation level isn't set by EF, it uses database default isolation level. In case of `Microsoft SQL Server` it will be `Read committed`. This isolation level says that concurrent transactions can read data, but if there is ongoing modification, other transactions will wait for it to complete, even if they want just read. Transaction will be held before `Commit()`  is called.

**When you don't specify transaction explicitly**:
Select statements and `SaveChangesAsync` will lead to separate transactions with the same isolation level defaulted to database. Transaction isn't held longer than it needs: in case of, for example, `SaveChangesAsync`, it will be there while all changes are written, starting from the moment when the method is called.

> Transaction (Process ID 71) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

This message appears when there are several transactions trying to get access to some resource, and one of them is trying to read data and the other one is trying to modify. In that case, to avoid dead lock, database will try to kill a transaction that will require lower amount of resources to rollback. In your case — it's a transaction that tries to read. Reads are lightwight in terms or weight of rollback.

**Summarizing:**
When you have one huge lock that holds one resource a huge amount of time, it stops other workers from accessing that resource as database just kills other workers' transactions when they try to read probably at that `var ids = entities.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();` point. When you rewrote your code, you got rid of long locks. More to that, as I can see from documentation to [BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/README.md), this extension uses internal transactions on each call, not affecting and not involving EF context. If that so, then it means that actual transactions live even less than one call to `SaveChangesAsync` when data changed not with the extension, but in usual EF way.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. The documentaion says "if we need multiple operations in single procedure then explicit transaction should be used", so I should not remove `BeginTransaction()` as I want to update/delete rows in multiple tables in a single procedure. I should instead move `.Select(x => ....` outside of the transaction, then maybe change the isolation level to something appropriate.

Comment: @Koji yes, that should affect the behaviour. Though it's unlikely that dead lock will go away as modification of the same rows sill will be presented and one transaction will be waiting for the other. A real helper here could be moving to synchronous execution and queuing. Also, you can check are there any waiting transactions or not by utilizing `SQL Server Management Studio` by just looking at active processes — they will be in idle state.

Comment: In my code, the .NET Core worker automatically creates a multiple threads and I don't think I can control it. One thing I can think of is to use `lock`. That'd ensure only one thread can do read/update/delete at a time, but I was trying to avoid using it as it'll slow the threads down significantly.

Comment: I heard that there is some sort of a "waiting time" configuration that determines how long the sql server waits until it throws a deadlock exception. Is it true? If you know it, could you please provide some web sites or documents explaining it? Well, it won't be a ideal solution but I'd like to try if it does exist such thing.

Comment: @Koji unfortunately, there is no such “waiting time” to configure, locks detection is automatic and happens in non-discreet intervals of time; when lock is found, exception is thrown at the same moment. You can try `ROWLOCK` optimizer hint probably, but be aware that in some cases it can lead to degradation of performance. So manual lock looks like a good solution here as it doesn't really matter on what side it will be taken — C# code or database, lock will be taken in any case.